# Entity Framework Core: How to return queryable<class> with 'using'?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

ToList() can work.

```
public List<class> Get()
{
     using (var db = new dbcontext())
     {
          return db.class.ToList();
     }
}
```

But AsQueryable() cannot work. How to get it working with using? I want to use queryable because it can get data faster than ToList().

EDIT

Decided to use dapper for select. EF Core for CUD. dapper's ToList()/Queryable faster in select comparing to EF's ToList() if want to use using().

Get 100k rows with using()

- Dapper ToList()/Queryable = 250 to 300ms
- EF's ToList() = 1300ms to 1500ms

Get 100k rows without using()

- EF's Queryable = 0.03ms.

Really like EF's queryable due to its fastest performance but no choice because I need to dispose, if not, bad performance when too many users like 500k users. Decided to use dapper instead for select.

Comment: Queryable does not "get data"

Comment: Thanks. Decided to use dapper for select. EF Core for CUD

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in a single method, you need to manage the lifetime of the `DbContext` outside `Get` method.

The `.ToList()` variant works because when calling `.ToList()` entity framework queries the data and stores the resulting objects. After that you do not need to query the database to access the data, hence the `DbContext` is not required anymore to access the list items.

When using `Queryable` you defer the query to a later point in time. This allows EF Core to create more efficient DB queries, because Linq Operatos like `Where()` can be translated to SQL when calling `ToList()` or similar methods. The `DbContext` is required to execute the actual SQL query and thus it needs to be kept alive.

Also take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext#lifetime for some guidelines on the lifetime of `DbContext`. The article is for EF6, but the concept applies to EF Core as well.

Comment: Thanks. Edited my first post. Decided to use dapper for select. EF Core for CUD.

Answer (score 0):

`AsQueryable` does not have data in memory. It's just a query and you are delaying the data allocation until it's used as for example `ToList`. You can further query on `AsQueryable` only condition your dbcontext should be open.

Comment: Thanks. Edited my first post. Decided to use dapper for select. EF Core for CUD.